# Существуют две таблицы в одной бд для веб-приложения Django. В одной из них содержаться запросы, в других - ответы на эти запросы

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, django, веб-программирование

Ниже приложен код для получения ответа на запросы по запросам.

```
q = Key.objects.get(Question=ques)      
a = Value.objects.get(id = q.id)
```

Get - получает один ответ на запрос. Но существуют ситуации, когда на один гет запрос (первый) выходит несколько ответов, и тогда выводит ошибку:

```
get() returned more than one Key -- it returned 3!
```

Как сделать так, чтобы вернуло сразу несколько значений?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вашему запросу может соответствовать более одного элемента в отношении, используйте метод `filter` вместо `get`. Он возвращает все объекты, соответствующие вашему условию:

```
q = Key.objects.filter(Question = ques) # заменяем на filter - получаем все объекты, подходящие под критерий
a = Value.objects.get(id = q.id) # так как id не повторяется, оставляем get
```

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/)